TeamCity: docker buildx not pushing to registry (but docker build works fine)
I am building some images with TeamCity with docker buildx but I cannot push these images to a private registry. The build is shown as successful, but when I look into the registry the image is not there. The same works fine for docker build.
I found these related issues:

using docker buildx failed to push image to resgistry: no such host
Standard docker push works but not buildx(docker-container) - ERROR exporting to image

They say that the network driver must be set to --driver-opt=network=host, but it still does not work for me. I have the following script:
name=container-builder
docker buildx ls | grep -q $name && docker buildx rm $name
docker buildx create --driver-opt network=host --use --name $name
docker buildx build -t registry.mydomain.com/myimage:latest --push --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 .

It runs the build without error, but the image is not in the registry.
When I run the regular docker build the image is pushed properly:
docker build -t registry.mydomain.com/myimage:latest --push .

I am running an ARM64 server and these are the version information:
$docker version

Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.9
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.13
 Git commit:        2936816
 Built:             Thu Feb  1 00:49:14 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm64
 Context:           default

$ docker buildx version
github.com/docker/buildx v0.13.1 7884339

I had it once running, I know it works, but I can't get it to run. Anyone an idea what the problem is?
[UPDATE]
I also made sure that buildx creates the right platforms with:
docker buildx create --driver-opt network=host --use --name $name --platform linux/arm64,linux/amd64

According to the docs, --push is only a valid option on buildx build and not on plain build. So it's weird that you say it works on build but not on buildx. https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/image/build/

@Hans Kilian I just checked it and it works. I know that it is not documented but when I use docker build ... --push it works.
